# Outros dados da conta com autenticação do facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, facebook, asp.net-core

Estou implementando autenticação por facebook e queria que, ao entrar na aplicação com os dados da conta, salvar também nome completo, foto, entre outros dados.

Pesquisando, consegui o seguinte código:

```
  facebookOptions.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthEvents
  {
       OnCreatingTicket = context => {
       string surName = context.User.Value<string>("last_name");
       context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, surName));

       return Task.FromResult(0); 
       }
  };
```

O sobrenome do usuário, aparece na variável `surName` porém não fica salvo em nenhum lugar.

Se alguém puder me ajudar a entender o que é `Identity.AddClaim` e como salvar os dados que vem no `User.Value<T>`. Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui solucionar o que precisava.

> Não é necessário o código que estava utilizando na pergunta.

Basta que, no `AccountController` na action `ExternalLoginCallback` você passe os valores que contém na Claims para o model:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
        }
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
            var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

            //apenas esse código para pegar o valor do Name que veio do provedor
            var name = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);


            return View("ExternalLogin", new ExternalLoginViewModel { Email = email, Nome = name  }); //valor da variável repassado para o model

        }
    }
```